Calculating Year over Year change for a Month in Pandas, from Excel
I have an excel file with raw data, which lists transaction data by month for facilities. There's the month/year, the facilityID, and then spend in that transaction. There can be multiple transactions for a facility in a month. I've managed to group the transactions by date and facilityID, with the total spend as the values. It looks something like this.

I'm trying to calculate the aggregate year-over-year change in TotalSpend, for say 2024-05-01 (May 2024). Some of the facilities may be new so they wouldn't have May 2023 data, or they might have dropped out or not yet reported the data so they wouldn't have May 2024 data. In both cases I want to exclude those facilities then from the calculation. I would also like to have a Quarterly year-over-year change, but I'm assuming I can just do the same thing I do for the May, but for April, May, and June when the data is available.
This is what I've tried so far, but I'm getting an error. I don't necessarily need to add it into the column in the df, just
May 2024      5%
would suffice for my purposes
Code - with some pseudocode if it makes sense
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def open_file(path, date_str, prev_date_str):
    df_raw = pd.DataFrame({'Date':["2024-05-01","2024-05-01","2024-05-01","2023-05-01","2024-05-01","2023-05-01","2023-05-01","2024-04-01","2022-05-01"],
                     'FacilityID': [6,6,5,5,1,6,6,4,6],
                     'TotalSpend': [100,200,5,5,90,190,150,500,200]
})
    df = df_raw.groupby(['Date','FacilityID'])['TotalSpend'].sum()
    #facilities = get complete list of facilities
    cur_month_vals = []
    prev_month_vals = []

    for facility in facilities:
        if df.loc[date_str][facility] and if df.loc[prev_date_str]:
            cur_month_vals.append(df.loc[date_str][facility].value)
            prev_month_vals.append(df.loc[prev_date_str][facility].value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = open_file("Path", '2024-05-01', prev_date_str= '2023-05-01')


How to make good reproducible pandas examples

Using the sample data as input:
import pandas as pd

df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": [
            "2024-05-01",
            "2024-05-01",
            "2024-05-01",
            "2023-05-01",
            "2024-05-01",
            "2023-05-01",
            "2023-05-01",
            "2024-04-01",
            "2022-05-01",
        ],
        "FacilityID": [6, 6, 5, 5, 1, 6, 6, 4, 6],
        "TotalSpend": [100, 200, 5, 5, 90, 190, 150, 500, 200],
    }
)

df_raw["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_raw["Date"]).dt.to_period("M").dt.to_timestamp()
df_raw = df_raw.set_index("Date")

df_grouped = df_raw.groupby([df_raw.index, "FacilityID"]).sum()

out = df_grouped.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        (date, fac)
        for date in pd.date_range(df_raw.index.min(), df_raw.index.max(), freq="MS")
        for fac in set(df_raw["FacilityID"])
    )
).reset_index(names=["Date", "FacilityID"])

out["Year"] = out["Date"].dt.year
out["Month"] = out["Date"].dt.month

out = out.sort_values(["Month", "Year"])

pct = (
    out.groupby(["FacilityID", "Month"])["TotalSpend"]
    .apply(lambda g: g.pct_change(fill_method=None))
    .reset_index(level=[0, 1], name="Change")
)

out = out.join(pct["Change"]).dropna()

         Date  FacilityID  TotalSpend  Year  Month    Change
51 2023-05-01           6       340.0  2023      5  0.700000
98 2024-05-01           5         5.0  2024      5  0.000000
99 2024-05-01           6       300.0  2024      5 -0.117647

